# Adjacent Blocks Modified Histogram Equalization (ABMHE) implementation / CLAHE

Tags: image, histogram, contrast

I am looking to implement a localized contrast enhancement on 16 bit grayscale (X-ray) images.  I am familiar with CLAHE, which works well in some case, but can often give blocky artefacts and over-enhancement of some areas.... the images I am working with require something better than standard CLAHE.  A lot of Googling has lead me to some modified versions of CLAHE - e.g. ABMHE - but I am struggling to find any implementations to trial - ideally in C# or C++, but I'm willing to translate from pretty much any language if required.  Any pointers gratefully received.

Tried (& dismissed) algorithms incliude CLAHE, suace, adaptive Hist EQ. based on unsharp mask techniques, bandpass filtering.

Comment: Please read the tags that you add. This had nothing to do with [the Processing programming language](https://processing.org). Also, don't invent tags, `local` is nothing.